# Running a vbs Sub from C#

Tags: c#, vbscript

Is it possible to execute a specific sub in a vbs file from a c# application?

I have looked at creating a Process and then launching it but can not find a way to specify which particular sub in the script file should be executed. Is there a way to specify this or is there a better way of doing it?

A vbs could look something like the sample below. What I want is from the C# code to launch either test1 or test2.

```
Public Sub test1
    msgbox "Hey1"
End Sub

Public Sub test2
    msgbox "Hey2"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Visual Basic (without the .Net) I used the [Script Control](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=D7E31492-2595-49E6-8C02-1426FEC693AC&displaylang=en) for this.

[This page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/184740) contains some documentation how to call it from good old VB.

Syntax looks something like this:

```
  Result = ScriptControl.Run("Name", arg1, arg2, ... argn)
```

---

Edit (after reading comment):
If you do not need the VBScript to run in your context (if you do not share objects), you could create a small application that runs the script out-of-process. Your main app is 64 bit, the helper app is 32-bit. You can still pass simple parameters.

Comment: Thanks to GvS and Christian for the tip about the scriptcontrol, however this does unfortunately not seem to work in 64bit Windows 7. If I set the target as x86 the application runs fine and the script is executed, but as soon as I switch it over to Any CPU or x64 it can not import the COM object.

Googeling for it brings up a number of posts about the MSScriptControl not working in a 64bit environment.

Setting the application to be 32bit is not an option, the application should run in x64 mode on a 64bit os so I'm afraid that using the ScriptControl doesn't work for me.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You use the Windows Script Control COM component and call its `Run` method. Here is a useful [link with code examples](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/184740).