# How to embed VBS in C# and run it?

Tags: c#, .net, vbscript

I have a VBScript that's working fine.  I have a C# program that can run the VBScript with the cscript program.

What I want to do is embed the VBS in a C# exe so it is one single file and be able to run the VBS file.  Is there any way for me to pass the embedded VBScript file to cscript as an argument or some other way to run an embedded VBS file?

Comment: relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409134/running-a-vbs-sub-from-c-sharp?rq=1

Answer (score 6):

```
Type scriptType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(Guid.Parse("0E59F1D5-1FBE-11D0-8FF2-00A0D10038BC"));

dynamic obj = Activator.CreateInstance(scriptType, false);
obj.Language = "vbscript";
string vbscript = "msgbox(\"test\")";
obj.Eval(vbscript);
```

Comment: working example of a WinForms app that does this: http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/srcview.aspx?dir=script&file=ScriptHost.zip

Comment: How am I supposed to format the syntax of the VBScript to make it work? The msgbox example works but I'm getting syntax error when trying to run my script with VBScript reserve words.

Comment: @L.B This doesn't work: `Wscript.Echo("hello")`. Any idea why?

Comment: @DanW The answer to your question (11 years late) is that `WScript.Echo` is only available when the script is run via the `WScript.exe` or `CScript.exe` host. This also applies to other WScript commands, such as `WScript.Sleep`.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is that you can execute CSCRIPT.EXE via a sub process:

```
Process.Start("cscript.exe", "C:\\myscript.vbs");
```

However, keep in mind that .NET and C# is very compatible with VBS scripting.  You might want to just rewrite the VBS code as a C# program directly.

Comment: How would that work with an embedded resource if there's no path? I'm using `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                      .GetManifestResourceStream("script.vbs"))`

Comment: extract your resource to a Temp File, execute CScript with the Temp File. Then delete the Temp file?

Comment: @PaulFarry Well obviously I could do that but I'm trying to find a way that does not expose the file.

Comment: @Jack sorry, but it wasn't obvious. you didn't state it in your question or comment that this was something you tested.

Comment: @PaulFarry I already mentioned that I could run the file from the C# program.  I said "What I want to do is embed the VBS in a C# exe so it is `one single file and be able to run the VBS file.`" and "some other way to run an embedded VBS file?"

Comment: I think your ideal solution would be to convert the VBS code into C# code.  You'll probably find that the C# code is much more reliable and can handle exceptions smoothly.  Also, code compiled into C# doesn't expose the VBS file ;)